# How to dynamically Goal Seek for multiple rows in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro in Excel VBA that will Goal Seek for multiple rows. Column B is my "Set Value", Column C is the value that changes, and Column D is my "Goal Value". Below is my current code. I am new to VBA so thank you for any help at all and your patience!

```
Sub dynamicgoalseek()

Dim i As Integer   ' i used for loop
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)

' used to count rows in column B
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

' start of loop
For i = 1 To LastRow


'set B to value in D by changing C
    Range("b", i).GoalSeek, _
    Goal:=Range("d", i), _
    ChangingCell:=Range("c", i)


' end loop
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Edit: I am getting an application-defined or object-defined error when I run it.

Comment: What doesn't work here?

Comment: Change your syntax for the `Range` object: `Range("B" & i)`

Comment: Oh good eye @cybernetic.nomad

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - Or, OP could use `Cells(i, "B")`.  I mentioned that just in case they're partial to using a comma there... Edit: Ah, actually OP used that style in declaring `lastRow`.

Comment: even better eye @BruceWayne :)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that was right! Thank you so much!

Comment: Let's get an answer and mark it correct so you all get points and we can get on with our lives.